# Multiple error '(' expected in code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.list;
import java.util.*;
public class PatientRecordSystem
{
  private int PATIENTMAX = 100;
  private int OBSERVATIONMAX = 50;

   private int current = 1;
   private int observationcurrent = 1;
   // current = patients, observationcurrent = observations count

   public PatientRecordSystem()
   {
       addPatient();
   }

   public void String addMeasurementObservationType()
   {

   }

   public void String addCategoryObservationType()
   {

   }

   public void String addPatient()
   {
   String PatientName = "James";
   String PatientID = "10122";

   }

   public void String addMeasurementObservation()
   {
   // for patient
   }

   public void String addCategoryObservation()
   {
   // for patient
   }
   // no interactive inputs, all static details.
   }
}
```

i'm unsure as to what is causing the error to appear as :

> PatientRecordSystem.java:17: error: '(' expected
>           public void String addMeasurementObservationType()
>                              ^ PatientRecordSystem.java:22: error: '(' expected
>           public void String addCategoryObservationType()
>                              ^ PatientRecordSystem.java:27: error: '(' expected
>           public void String addPatient()
>                              ^ PatientRecordSystem.java:34: error: '(' expected
>           public void String addMeasurementObservation()
>                              ^ PatientRecordSystem.java:39: error: '(' expected
>           public void String addCategoryObservation()

Comment: All your methods are declared as `void` *and* with a return type...

Comment: He also has an extraneous `}` and he's trying to import `java.util.list;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first issue is in your method declarations, you cannot declare your methods `public void String`

If your method **returns nothing** then it should be declared :

```
public void addMeasurementObservationType(){
    // ...
}
```

If your method **returns a String** then it should be declared :

```
public String addMeasurementObservationType(){
    return "the string to return";
}
```

> The second one is that you are importing `java.util.list;`

You should import :

```
import java.util.List;
```

> The third one is that you have an extra `}`

```
public void addCategoryObservation(){
    // for patient
    } <--- HERE
    // no interactive inputs, all static details.
}
```

My guess is that your code should look like :

```
class PatientRecordSystem {
    private int PATIENTMAX = 100;
    private int OBSERVATIONMAX = 50;

    private int current = 1;
    private int observationcurrent = 1;


    public PatientRecordSystem(){
        addPatient();
    }

    public void addMeasurementObservationType(){

    }

    public void addCategoryObservationType(){

    }

    public void addPatient(){
        String PatientName = "James";
        String PatientID = "10122";
    }

    public void addMeasurementObservation(){
        // for patient
    }

    public void addCategoryObservation(){
        // for patient
        // no interactive inputs, all static details.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple return types. If you declare void as your return type you can't return anything... i have modified your code to return type as void. (change accordingly!) hope it helps...

```
public class PatientRecordSystem {
private int PATIENTMAX = 100;
private int OBSERVATIONMAX = 50;

private int current = 1;
private int observationcurrent = 1;

// current = patients, observationcurrent = observations count

public PatientRecordSystem() {
    addPatient();
}

public void addMeasurementObservationType() {

}

public void addCategoryObservationType() {

}

public void addPatient() {
    String PatientName = "James";
    String PatientID = "10122";

}

public void addMeasurementObservation() {
    // for patient
}

public void addCategoryObservation() {
    // for patient
}
// no interactive inputs, all static details.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have something like this:

```
public void String addMeasurementObservationType()
   {

   }
```

and this is a contradiction/ makes no sense, your method should either return a `String` or just return nothing at all(`void`)

fix it by removing the String in the method return type

## Example

```
public void addMeasurementObservationType()
   {

   }
```

and this apply for all the methods with the same error...